# How can I customize Stripe Template in Sylius?

Tags: sylius, payum

I need to customize the Stripe Checkout template in Sylius 1.4.

Things I tried so far but did not work:

1- I added this config to config.yaml: 
`sylius_payum:
  template:
    layout: '@SyliusShop/payumlayout.html.twig'
    obtain_credit_card: '@SyliusShop/obtainCheckoutToken.html.twig'`

2- I tried to override `@SyliusPayum/Action/obtainCheckoutToken.html.twig`. Interestingly editing this file itself does not change the template!.

The only way that the template changes is to edit `@Payum/Stripe/Action/obtainCheckoutToken.html.twig.`

How I can override this file in Sylius?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turn out to be easy:

To override the file I needed to alter the `config` field  of stripe_checkout record at `sylius_gateway_config` table  of Sylius database as below.

```
UPDATE sylius_gateway_config SET config='{"publishable_key":"TEST_KEY","secret_key":"SECRET_KEY","payum.template.obtain_token":"SyliusPayumBundle::obtainCheckoutToken.html.twig","payum.template.layout":"SyliusPayumBundle::layout.html.twig"}' WHERE id=2
```

in my case the record id was 2.

`SyliusPayumBundle::obtainCheckoutToken.html.twig` and `SyliusPayumBundle::layout.html.twig` are the new overriding files.

The question is why the keys are not encrypted in the database and I think its not a good practice to have the override config at the database level.